# How can i merge two objects based on particular key and add a new key if we have 1 key but two different values in merged array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have multiple objects containing different keys, i want to merge it based on order(key),but it has some key that have same name but different value, so i want both the values, that's why i want to rename it in new merge array.
Array that i am getting is:

```
[{
    "question": "whats name",
    "question_type": "input",
    "is_required": true,
    "order": 1,
    "question_user":"employee",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 44,
            "choice": "Raj1"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "choice": "Raj2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "question": "new",
    "question_type": "dropdown",
    "is_required": true,
    "order": 2,
    "question_user":"employee",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "choice": "qw"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "choice": "qw2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "question": "new Data",
    "question_type": "input",
    "is_required": true,
    "order": 1,
    "question_user":"user",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "choice": "new"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "choice": "new2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "question": "Added Data",
    "question_type": "dropdown",
    "is_required": true,
    "order": 2,
    "question_user":"user",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "choice": "qw1"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "choice": "qw4"
        }
    ]
}]
```

object that i want

```
[{
    "question1": "whats name",
    "question2": "new Data",
    "question_type": "dropdown",
    "is_required": true,
    "order": 1,
    "question_user1":"employee",
    "question_user2":"user",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 44,
            "choice": "Raj1"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "choice": "Raj2"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "choice": "new"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "choice": "new2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "question1": "new",
    "question2": "Added Data",
    "question_type": "dropdown",
    "is_required": true,
    "order": 2,
    "question_user1":"employee",
    "question_user2":"user",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "choice": "qw"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "choice": "qw2"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "choice": "qw1"
        },
        {
            "id": null,
            "choice": "qw4"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I tried a lot but not able to make new keys in merged array based on order and question_user.Please help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a duplicate question using a different account?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
const mergedArray = [];

inputArray.forEach((item) => {
  const existingItem = mergedArray.find((mergedItem) => (
    mergedItem.order === item.order && mergedItem[`question_user${item.order}`] === item.question_user
  ));

  if (existingItem) {
    // Merge choices arrays
    existingItem.choices = existingItem.choices.concat(item.choices);
  } else {
    // Create a new merged object
    const newItem: MergedObject = {
      [`question${item.order}`]: item.question,
      question_type: item.question_type,
      is_required: item.is_required,
      order: item.order,
      [`question_user${item.order}`]: item.question_user,
      choices: item.choices
    };

    mergedArray.push(newItem);
  }
});

console.log(mergedArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, Again i getting 4 object but i want 2 object i have 4 object in which order is repeating, so 2 object will create,but right now getting 4 objects